# Optimizar consulta a base de datos Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Soy bastante nuevo en el framework Laravel, y me gustaría poder optimizar, con los recursos que ofrece, la siguiente consulta a la base de datos en el controlador. Que luego utilizo para listar los archivos correspondientes a la ruta especifica(en este caso un menú).*Lo he intentado de diferentes formas, pero esta es la única que me ha resultado*

```
public function searchByServices($ruta_id){
          $categorias = Categoria::where('tipo_id',$ruta_id)->get();
          $archivos = RutaTipo::select('archivos.archivo_id','archivos.desc_archivo',
          'archivos.nombre_fis_archivo','archivos.nombre_log_archivo','archivos.tamano_archivo',
          'archivos.version_archivo','archivos.docto_fis_archivo','docto_log_archivo',
          'marca_destacado','nro_descargas')
          ->join('categorias','ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id','=','categorias.tipo_id')
          ->join('archivos','categorias.categoria_id','=','archivos.cod_categoria')
          ->where('ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id',$ruta_id)->get();
          return view('archivos.servicepack',compact('archivos','categorias','ruta_id'));
        }
```

[image: Tablas]

Modelos
RutaTipo---->Categoria----->Archivo

```
class RutaTipo extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'ruta_tipos';
    protected $primarykey = 'ruta_tipo_id';
    protected $fillable   = ['prog_inicio_tipo','menu_tipo','ruta_tipo_archivo','prog_consulta_tipo'];
    protected $hidden     = ['ruta_tipo_id','cod_tipo','created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $dates      = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    public function categorias(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Categoria','tipo_id','ruta_tipo_id'); 
    }
}

class Categoria extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'categorias'; 
  protected $primarykey = 'categoria_id';
  protected $hidden = ['categoria_id','create_at','updated_at']; 
  protected $fillable = ['desc_categoria']; 
  protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at']; 
  protected $guard = ['categoria_id'];
  public function rutatipos(){
    return $this->belongTo('App\RutaTipo','ruta_tipo_id'); 
  }
  public function archivos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Archivo','cod_categoria','categoria_id');
  }
}

class Archivo extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'archivos';
    protected $primarykey = 'archivo_id';
    protected $fillable   = ['desc_archivo','nombre_fis_archivo','nombre_log_archivo',
                            'tamano_archivo','version_archivo','docto_fis_archivo',
                            'docto_log_archivo','marca_destacado','nro_descargas'];
    protected $hidden     = ['archivo_id','cod_archivo','cod_categoria','cod_subcategoria','created_at'];
    protected $guard      = ['archivo_id','cod_archivo','cod_categoria','cod_subcategoria'];
    protected $dates      = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function categoria(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','cod_categoria');
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente es una consulta muy sencilla, por favor lee la documentación de Laravel y Eloquent, tal y como lo hemos sugerido en otras preguntas que has hecho antes.

Comment: Logre llegar a $menu = RutaTipo::with('categorias.archivos')->where('ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id',$ruta_id)->get();
Ahora, tengo un problema al intentar acceder a los datos de archivos. Intente algo como $menu->categorias->archivos->desc_archivo pero no reconoce la propiedad archivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo que tu modelo RutaTipo tenga las relaciones con los modelos...así podes hacer uso de funciones como `whereHas` para sustituir los `join`.  Por ejemplo :

```
class RutaTipo extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function categorias(){
             return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'tipo_id', 
              'ruta_tipo_id');
     }

}


class Categoria extends Model
{
  /**
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
   */
   public function archivos(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Archivo::class, 'categoria_id', 
     'cod_categoria');
   }
}
```

Con tus modelos relacionados, podrías hacer la consulta de esta manera :

```
RutaTipo::select('marca_destacado', 'nro_descargas', 
        'docto_log_archivo')
        ->whereHas('categorias', function($query){
            $query->whereHas('archivos');
        })->with(['categorias' => function($query){
            $query->with('archivos:desc_archivo,nombre_fis_archivo,nombre_log_archivo,tamano_archivo,version_archivo,docto_fis_archivo');
            }])
        ->whereRutaTipoId($ruta_id)->get();
```

Comment: y si colocas el ejemplo? para que tu aporte este mas completo y no quede a medias?

Comment: Eres un dios!! De aquellos que me han respondido, eres el primero que se da el tiempo. Hay un par de cosas que no comprendo. Por ejemplo, porque no puedo, o como podria incluir el metodo paginate a la sentencia que genere, y en la respuesta que me presentas me arroja error de sintax antes de ->whereRutaTipoId por un corchete } . De verdad te pasaste con lo anterior.

Comment: Primero, para paginar, lo unico que tenes hacer es reemplazar el `->get()`, por el `->paginate`, si me olvide un `;` despues del `$query->with('archiv....` ... ahi lo edito

Comment: Incluso, lo acabo de optimizar aprovechando Laravel $menu = RutaTipo::with('categorias.archivos')->where('ruta_tipos.ruta_tipo_id',$ruta_id)->get(); Pero, aun no encuentro la manera de paginar los archivos que me trae de esa ruta en esas categorias. Además no hallo, por el momento, como obtener en la vista los datos de los archivos. Intente algo como $ruta->categorias->archivos->desc_archivo

Comment: Me di cuenta, que extrae justo la relacion que quiero, solo que cuando voy a la relacion con los archivos, entrega una colección vacía. Lo intente asi y con eager loading.